# not match expected type

Tags: haskell

How can I solve this error and make my code work ?

My data type :

```
   data ID x = ID ( ( x, Mark ), [ ID x ] ) 
   data Mark = Marked | Unmarked
```

Show instance:

```
  instance  Show a  => Show ( ID a )  where

           show t  = go " " t   where 

                  go aP ( ID ( (x, Marked ), z ) ) =

                           aP ++ x ++ "\n"
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' against inferred type `a'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the instance declaration at Dictionary.hs:117:23
  Expected type: ID [Char]
  Inferred type: ID a
In the second argument of `go', namely `t'
In the expression: go "" t
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Could you describe what you WANT your show instance for ID to do?

Comment: @Sarah I am trying to show the tree. But, for this case, I have stored digit as char. To see tree, look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244343/visiting-each-node

Comment: The implementation of `go` is relevant for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED:

I'm finding your intentions difficult to decipher, but I think perhaps you want to represent the tree-structure as a string? Here's a demo implementation that shows you how it could be done (in a quick, hacky way.)

```
data ID x = ID ((x, Mark), [ID x]) 
data Mark = Marked | Unmarked

instance Show a => Show (ID a) where
    show (ID ((x, _), ids)) = "Val: " ++ show x ++
                              ", Children: " ++ 
                              (show $ map show ids)
```